# PHP | Удалить тэги со строки

Tags: php

У меня есть вот такое описание.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При получение данных я получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне удалить тэги? Я хочу сделать моё описание слитным.

Comment: Конкретно какой спец символ?

Comment: @Bloom , скорее всего перенос на новую строчку

Comment: br ?....................

Comment: Спецсимволы все, которые находятся на картинке

Comment: Это не спецсимволы, а тэги. Не путайте термины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удаления тегов используйте [функцию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) `strip_tags`.

Первым параметром передаете строку содержающую получаемый текст, во второй параметр можете передать тэги, которые необходимо оставить.

```
$text = '<p>Параграф.</p><!-- Комментарий --> <a href="#fragment">Еще текст</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Удаляем все тэги
echo strip_tags($text);
//Разрешаем тэг a 
echo strip_tags($text, '<a>');
// Разрешаем p и a
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```